# IndexedDB.open callbacks not called on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I am trying to use IndexedDB, and everything was working well, up until a few hours ago when my .open() callbacks stopped being called on Chrome (tested on Safari and it worked fine).

```
RT.prototype.setupIndexedDB = function (callback) {
  var dbName = "test";
  var dbVersion = 1;
  var indexedDB = window.indexedDB ||
                  window.webkitIndexedDB ||
                  window.mozIndexedDB;

  console.log("setup indexed db");
  var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    console.log("db request success");
  };

  request.onblocked = function(e) {
    console.log("DB open blocked", e);
  };

  request.onerror = function(err) {
    console.log("error", err);
  };

  request.onversionchange = function(err) {
    console.log("onversionchange", err);
  };

  request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    console.log("upgrade needed");
  };
};
```

I looked into the Chrome developer tools IndexedDB and nothing is there...

Anyone has an idea on what's happening?

Thank you

**EDIT: Completely restarting the browser did the trick, but I'm still very interested in knowing what happened.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Were you experimenting with deleting the database around the same time? IndexedDB can get into a weird (though correct, according to the spec) state if there's a blocked pending deleteDatabase operation. E.g. the code below. If all else fails you can check chrome://indexeddb-internals, which will tell you if there are any pending open or delete operations that are mucking things up.

```
var request = indexedDB.open("test", 1);
request.onblocked = function(e) {
  console.log("DB open blocked", e);
};

request.onerror = function(err) {
  console.log("DB open error", err);
};

request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
  console.log("DB open upgrade needed");
};

request.onsuccess = function(e) {
  db = request.result;
  console.log("DB open success");
  db.onversionchange = function(e) {
    console.log("DB got a versionchange event")
  }
  request = indexedDB.deleteDatabase("test");
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    console.log("delete success will not be called")
  }
  request.onblocked = function(e) {
    console.log("delete was blocked");
    request = indexedDB.open("test", 1);
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
      console.log("success won't be called");
    };
    request.onblocked = function(e) {
      console.log("blocked won't be called", e);
    };
    request.onerror = function(err) {
      console.log("error won't be called", err);
    };
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
      console.log("upgradeneeded won't be called");
    };
  };
};
```

Comment: No, I was not deleting the database but there was pending requests I reckon. Thank you for your answer.